# html in php to call image

Tags: php, html, image

```
<?php if ($this->checkPosition('image')) : ?>
<?php
echo "<table class=\"remove-margin-t\"  cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"97%\"  align=\"center\" border=\"0\" style=\"max-width:625px; border:1px solid;\" background=\"..\images";
?>
<?php
echo $this->renderPosition('image')
<?php
echo ".png\">";
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am trying to figure out how to call the image properly.  echo for image is called and has a specific name like 'pink','blue','green' etc.  However, it depends on the position part...

This is what it is supposed to look like in html.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="97%" align="center" border="0" style="max-width:625px; border:1px solid #CCC"  background="http://localhost/images/[insert color name here].png" >
```

Here is the original php

```
<?php if ($this->checkPosition('color')) : ?>
<?php echo $this->renderPosition('color'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I am sure it must be a '\' or '"' issue.

Best,

Steven

To Jared:

Do you mean like this?

```
<?php if ($this->checkPosition('image')) : ?>
<?php
echo "<table class=\"remove-margin-t\"  cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"97%\" align=\"center\" border=\"0\" style=\"max-width:625px; border:1px solid;\" background=\"../images/";
echo $this->renderPosition('image')
echo ".png\">";
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Does putting a slash at the end of images help, `background=\"../images/"`

Comment: You've gone a little PHP-tag crazy there, huh? It is, it isn't, it is, it isn't, open, closed, open, closed, open again! Do one or the other (to `echo` or not to `echo`, this is the question).

Comment: even if I do this background=\"../images/"; it still is broken, :(

Comment: <?php if ($this->checkPosition('image')) : ?>
<?php
echo "<table class=\"remove-margin-t\"  cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"97%\" align=\"center\" border=\"0\" style=\"max-width:625px; border:1px solid;\" background=\"../images/";
echo $this->renderPosition('image')
echo ".png\">";
?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Ignore the errors, but I'd probably use a `HEREDOC` and a `$color` variable: http://codepad.org/akAfjKKl (If I'm not using a template technique.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open/close PHP tags on every line of PHP code. Your code may be rewritten this way:

```
<?php

if ($this->checkPosition('image')) {
    echo '<table class="remove-margin-t" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="97%"  align="center" border="0" style="max-width:625px; border:1px solid;" background="../images"' . $this->renderPosition('image') . '.png">';
}

?>
```

I replaced some double quotes with single quotes to avoid using backslashes everywhere.
I concatenated your text so that only one `echo` is used.

And I fixed a possible mistake at the end of the first `echo`: I replaced the blackslash by a slash, since directory separators in URLs are slashes.

Comment: Now, no `endif`... Also note your quotes are still a little off.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  I am looking at the code in Notepad ++ and it greys out completely after png.

Comment: @PrePCATStudent: check you are using the latest version of the code I posted in my answer (I edited several times). I am using Notepad++ too and the syntax coloring looks fine.

Comment: yeah, it's fine now...now I am trying to figure out how why all my css no longer works...thanks for the help!

Comment: Jocelyn, I edited to add curly braces (so that the gotchas associated with that style in PHP aren't transferred accidentally).

Comment: I tried your version as well from codepad and my css breaks...do I have to do the entire table within the php?  or does that not matter.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check the HTML source code of the page in your web browser. It may help locate the problem. Also, check if you are not missing a slash just after "images" in the code I posted above (since I don't know what the output of `$this->renderPosition('image')` is, I can't tell for sure if a slash need to be added or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what object '$this' is, nor do I know what the method checkPosition does
Also, what output 'renderPosition('color') produces.

either way, this code

```
<?php if ($this->checkPosition('color')) : ?>
<?php echo $this->renderPosition('color'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

is improper, and should be written as:

```
<?php
if ($this->checkPosition('color')) {
     echo $this->renderPosition('color');
} 
?>
```

With that said, the server tags "?php" and "?" represent the beginning and end of server code. So outside of those tags is standard html markup, generally.

So, you can use html markup outside of server code as so,

```
<?php if ($this->checkPosition('color')) { ?>
      <div style="width:97%;text-align:center;max-width:625px;border:1px solid #CCC;background-image:url('<?php echo "http://localhost/images/" . $this->renderPosition('color') . ".png"; ?>');display:inline-block;position:relative;">
          &nbsp;
      </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I turned your table into a div, and used CSSstyleAttributes, instead of depreciated html attributes.

Also, I am also assuming the output of renderPosition is a filename, without the file extension.

EDIT:

localhost refers to your own computer.

You may want to use:

```
echo "//" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/images/" . $this->renderPosition('color') . ".png";
```

in place of

```
 echo "http://localhost/images/" . $this-renderPosition('color') . ".png";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  It is literally 'pink'.  So for the top code, it will display the word 'pink' but will not display the background image as pink.png from the location...that is what I am essentially trying to do.  Also, I am editing this for 'Zoo' by yootheme.  So I am using their own code and editing it to do what I would like it to do. :)

Comment: in that case the code I revised should output a div tag with the inline-style attribute "background-image: url('http://localhost/images/ping.png')".. which will work if the file exists at that location.

the file (ping.png), is it a pattern, to be repeated?


what is the width and height of the image file?

The html encoded space "&'nbsp;", without the apostrophe ( ' ), ensures that there is content in the div tag.